# Using wxCreatePersistentObject to save tabs in a memory

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am working on saving tabs in memory using wxCreatePersistentObject, however I encountered some problems.

Using http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_persistence.html#persistence_defining
I am going step by step to create this persistentclass. I want to save tabpanel, which is inherited from auiNotebook.

```
class myPersistentClass : public wxPersistentObject{
public:
  myPersistentClass(TabPanel *panel);
  wxString GetKind() const;
  wxString GetName() const;
  void Save() const;
  bool Restore();
  TabPanel * panel_;
  wxPersistentObject * wxCreatePersistentObject (PropertyTabPanel *panel);
};
```

here is my definition:

```
  myPersistentClass::myPersistentClass(TabPanel *panel):wxCreatePersistentObject(panel)  {
  }

  wxPersistentObject * wxCreatePersistentObject (TabPanel *panel){
    return new myPersistentClass(panel);
  }

  wxString myPersistentClass::GetKind() const{
    return "PropertyTabPanel";
  }

  wxString myPersistentClass::GetName() const{
    return "namesomething";
  }

  void myPersistentClass::Save() const{
    wxPersistentObject::SaveValue("something", this);
  }

  bool myPersistentClass::Restore(){
    return wxPersistentObject::RestoreValue(GetName(), this);
  }
```

It gives ma a compiler error for the constructor. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Also if someone could tell me if I am on the right track to creating this wxPersistentObject

Comment: As we have explained to you several times: this is the wrong approach.

Comment: @ravenspoint I am going of with different approach. It still would be nice to know how to use this wxpersistentclass for future reference. I guesss it was made in wxwidgets for some purpose to use it? I don't know why is there a negative vote on that. This is completely a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really not clear what you're trying to do here. Persistent objects save their state in persistent storage (e.g. on disk) when they're destroyed and restore it when they're created again. A typical example is a top level window remembering its size and position between the program runs or a notebook remembering its last selected page. So if you want to save your `TabPanel` state in this way, you would define `PersistentTabPanel`, but unless `TabPanel` doesn't derive from `wxWindow`, you should inherit it from `wxPersistentWindow<TabPanel>` and not `wxPersistentObject` itself directly.

As for the error in the ctor, calling `wxCreatePersistentObject()` in the ctor initializer list just doesn't make any sense from C++ point of view, you use the initializer list to initialize the base classes and members and this function is, of course, neither. As the documentation you link to states, you need to *define* this function taking `TabPanel*`.

Comment: it doesn't save the full object just kind of part of it like position, size etc. not controls etc?

Comment: Yes, it only saves the selected object properties, it absolutely doesn't save the object in the sense of fully serializing it.